# Using custom coordinates with QGraphicsScene

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I am experimenting with a WYSIWYG editor that allows a user to draw shapes on a page and the Qt graphics scene support seems perfect for this.  However, instead of working in pixels I want all my `QGraphicsItem` objects to work in tenths of a millimetre but I don't know how to achieve this.

For example:

```
// Create a scene that is the size if an A4 page (2100 = 21cm, 2970 = 29.7cm)
QGraphicsScene* scene = new QGraphicsScene(0, 0, 2100, 2970);
// Add a rectangle located 1cm across, 1cm down, 5cm wide and 2cm high
QGraphicsItem* item = scene->addRect(100, 100, 500, 200);
...
QGraphicsView* view = new QGraphicsView(scene);
setCentralWidget(view);
```

Now, when I display the scene above I want the shapes to appear at correct size for the screen DPI.  Is this simply a case of using `QGraphicsView::scale` or do I have to do something more complicated?

Note that if I was using a custom QWidget instead then I would use `QPainter::setWindow` and `QPainter::setViewport` to create a custom mapping mode but I can't see how to do this using the graphics scene support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QGraphicsView::scale` should do the job. But I prefer setting the [transform](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qgraphicsview.html#setTransform). It gives me much more control over how the scene is displayed. But that's because I need things like rotation, flipping, etc. It also allow me to track what I did to the scene.

Answer (score 0):

Stephen Chu set me on the right path - using `scale` seems to work.

```
const qreal xScale = physicalDpiX() / 254.0;
const qreal yScale = physicalDpiY() / 254.0;
view->scale(xScale, yScale);
```

This results in measurements that look accurate on screen.